# How to typecast C (or C++) object by the number of bytes

Tags: c++, c

I have a void* named Example1 which points to a dynamically allocated object in the heap, however I do not know the data type of this object, only its size. How would I typecast the void* so that the program knows the size of the object?
For example, lets say I have this:

```
void* Example1;
Example1 = malloc(5); //A char* of size 5
```

Now assume all I know is that Example1 points to an array of 5 ???
Instead of this statement:

```
*((char*) Example1);
```

Is there a statement similar to this:

```
*( ((object of size 5)*) Example1);
```

I am just looking for a way to typecast based on the number of bytes and not the name of the object. Anything would be helpful. If there is a way to do something like this in C++, I would appreciate it as well. Thanks for your help!

Comment: You can't.  And if you're in C++, you should be using a type-safe collection (e.g. a `std::vector`), which retains information about the size.

Comment: You should refrain from `void *` pointers and use pointers to base classes and smart pointers.  Also refrain from using dynamic memory unless absolutely necessary.  Research "memory leak c++" for information.

Comment: I realize this, however I cannot for my purpose. I am actually trying to make a templated struct in C, sort of. I have it functional with individual objects so now I am trying to make it less code. I realize I will have to use it slightly differently but I have already made the interface for it.

Comment: I have a way to keep track of the size, what I need is a way to typecast to the size.

Comment: I suppose I could access it as a char* and simply access as many char's as I need to meet the actual size of the object.

Comment: Are sizes known at compile-time? Can target types be of the same size?

Comment: At compile time: yes. While I could write the program to handle a specific data type, I am doing something where I am somewhat making a templated struct so I need it able to handle objects of variable sizes. Hence casting by number of bytes, not by object name.

Comment: template <size_t size> struct map; template struct map<1> { typedef char target_type; }; ... and other specializations, then cast as static_cast<map<your_known_size>::target_type*>(object)

Comment: Thanks for the C++ idea. That one I was just curious about. Unfortunately I need to write the program in C so if you have any ideas for that I would love to hear them.

Comment: What if you have several types with the same size?

Comment: C and C++ are different languages. You need to choose which one you use.

Comment: Is C++ relevant here?

Comment: I am using C, I was just curious as to the answer for C++.

Comment: I am writing a segment of the code, it literally needs to return the value as a hexadecimal value and manipulate it in a certain way, but it needs to know the right size to grab.

Comment: UPVOTING: great question, and lots of wrong answers. I confess I don't know if my answer applies to C++ or not.

Answer (score 1):

It probably is different in C and in C++. They are really distinct languages today (even if C++ is *partly* compatible and inter-operable with a *subset* of C). You need to choose which one you'll be using.

In C (and also in C++) a pointer (to a non-`void` type) can be used as an array; so code

```
char * p = malloc(24);
```

BTW, in C++ you should avoid `malloc` (if you use it, you need to cast its result in C++) and you should prefer `new`, and preferably use standard [containers](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/) (and [smart pointers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smart_pointer)). BTW, using directly `new` in C++ is often poor taste (since you should use containers or strings).

then you can access `p[10]` or `p[i]` if the index `i` is non-negative and less than 24. (otherwise, it is [undefined behavior](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) because of the [buffer overflow](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buffer_overflow)).

In genuine C++11, you want to use `std::string`, or at least `std::vector` or `std::array`

However, raw pointers like `p` above never know the size of the memory zone. You *always* should know it yourself, perhaps by putting it in some other variable (or field). In C (but not in C++) you might use [flexible array members](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flexible_array_member).

in C, you may want to use `strdup`, e.g. as

```
char* ptr = NULL;
char buf[64];
snprintf (buf, sizeof(buf), "foo%d", i+2);
ptr = strdup(buf);
```

Of course, you'll need at some later point to call `free(ptr);` so read more about [C memory management](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_dynamic_memory_allocation).

in C++ you probably want to use `std::string`, perhaps as

```
std::string res = "foo" + std::to_string(i+2);
```

(even if that particular example is not very efficient)

See some websites like [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/) or [cplusplus](http://www.cplusplus.com/) (they both have material on C and on C++).

Comment: I'm using C. Was just curious about the same thing in C++

Answer (score 1):

**`char`** IS the object of **size 1, by definition**.  It may not be the only object of size 1, but it's also the one which the **strict aliasing rule** allows you to use, regardless of the dynamic type of the object.

So you already have the correct approach, stop looking for alternatives.

If you didn't mean `(object of size 1)` but `(object of size 5)`, then `char[5]` will do nicely.

Then there's a whole other question about what operations make sense on an object whose size you know but whose type you do not.  Not all objects are trivially copyable!

Comment: Thanks. And yes, I know. I wrote a program to handle that though so I am prepared. But I will use that idea of char[x]

Answer (score 1):

In C++, you will probably be able to solve your problem using one of the STL containers like `std::vector` or the string class `std::string`.

As for a solution in C, there's no direct way of getting the amount of memory allocated for a given `void*` return of `malloc`. But you *could* stub `malloc` and maintain a table of allocated sizes yourself. But the maintenance of that table could prove problematic; as you will have to deal with `free` and the variants of `malloc` (`calloc` &c.) as well.

It's probably best not to fight either language and work on a design that fits into C or C++ more neatly.

Comment: Thanks, and I would prefer to however I was hired to make a program to fit a certain function, no matter how bad the idea is. I am getting paid though so I won't argue.

Comment: I think that, in the long term, any data table-type solution will cause more problems. You are only a whisker away from undefined behaviour here, so be careful.

Answer (score 0):

No problem, just create a pointer to an array of  characters, and assign the address of your buffer to that:

```
#include <stdio.h>

char *buf = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
char (*c5p)[5];

int main(int ac, char *av[]) {
    c5p = (void*)buf;
    printf("%c %c\n", *(char*)c5p, *(char*)(c5p + 1));
}
```

As you would expect, this prints "a f", since `c5p` is a pointer to 5-byte objects.